# It is possible to use both Dependency and Interface connections in Component diagram? What is the difference?

Tags: architecture, dependencies, uml, components, component-diagram

i would like to ask what is the difference between **Dependency** connection and **Interface/Port** when they are used in one component diagram.

My thought is that **Interface/Port** need to be used when there is some data flow between components and **Dependency** is used when one component is using some of another components methods or functions. Is this right?

Another question about Dependency connection: is it necessary to use "*use*" title on connection?

I have read many tutorials but every is different and one is using "*use*" title another is not. It is same with definition of connections.

[image: Here is my diagram]
<sub>(source: [skrisa10 at student.fiit.stuba.sk](http://student.fiit.stuba.sk/~skrisa10/component.png))</sub>

I made it in VS 2012.

Thank you for your answers, realy appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are difference between **Dependency** and **Interface/port** connections.

**Interface/Port** connections are used in order to specify a type (data type, services) of the connection needed or used by a given **Component/Port**.

**Dependency** are used in order to model the fact that an element depends from another. This does not have a very specific semantic.

**Usage**, which are **Dependency** with <>, model the fact that a **Component** uses another or an **Interface** (this pattern is a requirement of the usage of  **Provided/Required Interfac ** usage).

Hoping it helps.

Comment: Hello, i want to ask you one more thing. Should I place <<use>> on dependency or it is up on me? Is it necessary for the good component diagram? btw Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: You have two different thins: 1) Dependency 2) Usage (which is depicted as a dependency with <<use>>).
A good diagram is a clear diagram so do you want to express that a component depends to another (in this case it is a dependency) or that a component uses another (in this case it is a usage).